# 忠美聖愛仁義利義好哀恕: How do I segment this proverb into separate words?

Tags: grammar

I saw a single row of characters with no punctuation:

> 忠美聖愛仁義利義好哀恕

I believe this is a proverb relating to Confucian values, but I can't break it into separate words.

Zhongmei (忠美) might be loyalty.

Sheng-ai (聖愛) is probably love between humans and gods.

Ren-yi (仁義) is compassion.

Li (利) might be benefit.

I can't even figure out the boundaries of the words, much less the grammar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would attempt to break it up as follows:
忠美圣  爱  仁义  利义  好哀恕

And from there we have something like:
The honest and virtuous sage loves benevolence, righteousness, morality, and justice [and here is where I am somewhat uncertain because of the many possible readings of 好] and readily sympathizes with and forgives others.

Answer (score 2):

I think there may be a character missing. Like: 忠美圣  爱仁义  X利义  好哀恕

Or 利 might be 礼, like 忠美圣  爱仁义礼义  好哀恕

Answer (score 0):

It's meaningless, just some words randomly put together.
Nothing related to Confucianism.